# Got 'Enter values for precautions" popup in Oracle Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle Developer to execute the SQL queries. I got this popup:

> Enter value for precaution

when I'm trying to execute an insert query. Does anyone know why I'm getting this popup?

Comment: Yes  This is a same question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to answer if you posted statement you ran.

Meanwhile, that's probably because `insert` contains `&` which indicates a bind variable. Something like this:

```
insert into test (name) values ('Is this what&precaution?');
```

What to do? Run `set define off` first, then run the `insert`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.